# Fragment freezes when switched to landscape mode

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

I have a fragment in my app that takes half of my activity. In that fragment is a view pager that has 3 other fragments...

Now everything works properly when i am **initially** in landscape or portrait mode. But then when I switch to landscape in my emulator (*My Emulator is **GenyMotion**, which works 5 times as fast as the original AVD Manager.*)

The fragment still displays in my activity properly, but it's frozen. **Which means I can't click buttons or swipe between the** `ViewPager` **or anything else.**

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong. Is it my emulator or my code? Help is highly appreciated... Thanks!

Comment: While changing orientation, your activity Re-creates itself and Re-draws everything.Are you using any background thread to load views ?

Comment: No, I'm not, everything is happening on the main UI thread.. I'm building a mock up so there are no background processes as of now...

Answer (score 0):

Make use of onSavedInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState().

onSaveInstanceState() saves state of current activity before changing screen orientation and onRestoreInstanceState() restores state when orientation is changed

```
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle icicle) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(icicle);
}
```

write above method in your parent activity.

To restore activity state, you can use onRestoreInstanceState() as well as onCreate().

Difference is onRestoreInstanceState() is called after onStart() and onCreate() is called before onStart().

So in your case you can just use onSaveInstanceState() in parent activity. Activity state is saved before orientation is changed and onCreate() will recreate your activity with previous saved state.

Comment: protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
 
}  try putting this method along with onSaveInstanceState()

Comment: still doesn't work... Do you think it may be a problem with my emulator?